# How to Combine Columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to combine two tables results without duplicating/increasing values when using join. (company and team they have ids from each other table)

I am trying to get the count of teams that support a country .
and the count from companies that support a country.

The tables are similar to this.

```
companies | country
----------+--------
one       | USA
two       | CAN
tree      | USA
four      | MEX
```

and the output would be the count of the number of supporters for each country.

```
country | company_no_supp
--------+----------------
USA     | 2
CAN     | 1
MEX     | 1
```

Now I would have the same for team.

```
team    | country
--------+----------
t1      | CAN
t2      | CAN
t3      | CAN
t4      | MEX
t5      | MEX
t6      | USA
t7      | USA
t8      | USA
```

and the result:

```
country | team_no_supp
--------+-----------
USA     | 3
CAN     | 3
MEX     | 2
```

What I want to do is to join both results into one and keep the team_no_supp and the country_no_supp.

like:

```
country | team_no_supp | companies_no_supp
--------+--------------+-------------------
USA     | 3            | 2
CAN     | 3            | 1
MEX     | 2            | 1
```

I have tried joins (all sort of them). However I am not so experience yet on sql.

Comment: Post your code that you have tried so far the the results (why they are not what you want)

Comment: Please show what you have tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `JOIN` until you do not need to enrich your data with new attributes, you can use `UNION`: it is lighter and has more abilities for parallel processing without large data exchange:

```
select
  country,
  count(team) as team_no_supp,
  count(company) as companies_no_supp
from (
  select
    country,
    company,
    null as team
  from companies

  union all

  select
    country,
    null as company,
    team as team
  from teams
)
group by country
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac2dba5303ba33fb55ff8af50736ee8e)*

Comment: Thank you, I havent learnt how about making subqueries on the from. this was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below

```
 SELECT TabAuxA.country,
        team_no_supp,
       company_no_supp  FROM  (SELECT country, COUNT(*) as company_no_supp
   FROM table1
  GROUP BY country ) as TabAuxA
  INNER JOIN  (SELECT country, COUNT(*) as team_no_supp
     FROM table2
  GROUP BY country ) as TabAuxB ON TabAuxA.country = TabAuxB.country
```

OBS:
Don't forget to replace the table names (table1 and table2) with the tables you are using

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries in the from clause:

```
select c.country, c.company_no_supp, t.teams_no_supp from 
(select country, count(*) company_no_supp from @companies group by country) c
join 
(select country, count(*) teams_no_supp from @teams group by country) t on c.country = t.country
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you might not have the same countries in both tables.  I would suggest a `FULL JOIN`:

```
select country, coalesce(cnt_a, 0) as cnt_a, 
       coalesce(team_no_supp, 0) as team_no_supp
from (select country, count(*) as cnt_a
      from a
      group by country
     ) a full join
     b
     using (country);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that will also cover the case of not all countries being present in both tables:

```
WITH companies (company, country)
AS
(
  SELECT 'one',  'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'two',  'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tree', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'four', 'MEX' FROM DUAL 
), teams (team, country) AS
(
  SELECT 't1', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't2', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't3', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't4', 'MEX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't5', 'MEX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't6', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't7', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 't8', 'USA' FROM DUAL
), companies_cnt(country, cnt) AS
(
  SELECT country, count(company) FROM companies
  GROUP BY country
), teams_cnt(country, cnt) AS
(
  SELECT country, count(team) FROM teams
  GROUP BY country
), combined_data (country, t, c) AS
(
  SELECT country, cnt, 0 FROM teams_cnt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT country, 0, cnt FROM companies_cnt
)
SELECT COUNTRY, MAX(t) as team_no_supp, MAX(c) as companies_no_supp from combined_data GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use merge when exists insert when not exists update something like this:
MERGE INTO employees e
USING hr_records h
ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (id, address)
VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);